# Using Tasks with Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: task

Good Day,

I want to use tasks, to instantiate all classes within a Namespace, and then have each task add it's executing method add it's results to a List.

So each class within the namespace will have the same method. eg. DoWork(parameters)

Then when all the Tasks have finished, the List object will be filled and returned.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry it's C#